# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

As title, I couldn't open my rails app.
Need help as I couldn't solve this through google.
I'm using rails 4.2.1 and ruby 2.2.1

Below are the error messages.

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1-openssl@global/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
~/projects/linktest/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/projects/linktest/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/projects/linktest/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1-openssl/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/projects/linktest/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
~/projects/linktest/config.ru:1:in `new'
~/projects/linktest/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:51:in `eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:51:in `load_config'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:42:in `initialize'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `new'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `run'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Here are my gem list.

```
actionmailer (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
actionpack (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
actionview (4.2.1)
activejob (4.2.1)
activemodel (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
activesupport (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
airbrake (4.1.0)
anjlab-bootstrap-rails (2.3.1.2)
annotate (2.6.8)
arel (6.0.0, 4.0.2)
auto-facebook (0.4)
bcrypt (3.1.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
better_errors (0.9.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bootstrap_helper (4.2.3)
bootstrappers (4.2.1)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4)
bundler (1.9.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
byebug (4.0.4)
cape (1.8.0)
capistrano (3.4.0, 2.15.5)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
carrierwave (0.10.0)
carrierwave-meta (0.0.5)
chronic (0.10.2)
chunky_png (1.3.4)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.1.0, 4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1)
colorize (0.7.5)
columnize (0.9.0)
compass (0.12.7)
compass-rails (1.1.7)
dalli (2.7.4)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (3.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.4.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
faraday (0.9.1)
font-awesome-rails (3.2.1.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
globalid (0.3.3)
hashie (3.4.0)
high_voltage (2.2.1)
highline (1.7.1)
hike (1.2.3)
hipchat (1.4.0)
httparty (0.13.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.2.12, 1.5.3)
jquery-rails (4.0.3, 3.1.2)
json (1.8.2, 1.7.7)
jwt (1.4.1)
loofah (2.0.1)
magic_encoding (0.0.2)
mail (2.6.3, 2.5.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (2.4.3, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.5.1, 5.4.3, 4.7.5, 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.0)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
mysql2 (0.3.18)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.9.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
oauth2 (1.0.0)
omniauth (1.2.2)
omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)
open_graph_helper (0.2.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
powder (0.3.0)
power_assert (0.2.2)
pry (0.10.1)
pry-nav (0.2.4)
pry-remote (0.1.8)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.6.0, 1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.1, 4.0.0)
rake (10.4.2, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.2.0, 4.0.0)
rmagick (2.13.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
rvm-capistrano (1.5.6)
sass (3.4.13, 3.2.19)
sass-rails (5.0.3, 4.0.5, 4.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.1)
seo_helper (1.0.2)
settingslogic (2.0.9)
simple_form (3.0.3)
slop (3.6.0)
spring (1.3.3)
sprockets (2.12.3, 2.11.0)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4, 2.0.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.10)
sshkit (1.7.1)
test-unit (3.0.8, 2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.43)
uglifier (2.7.1)
warden (1.2.3)
web-console (2.1.2)
whenever (0.9.4)
will_paginate (3.0.3)
```

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the ruby you think you are? Your error shows a path with `ruby-2.1.1` in it.

Comment: @smathy yea, i did use 'rvm use 2.2.1' and check with 'rvm list' before create the rails app/

Comment: @smathy as you mentioned above, I tried bundle update with my ruby 2.1.1, then it works. Don't really know why the error is in 2.1.1 but not the ruby i'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the additional information in your comments I think this is probably a spring caching issue, try stopping spring with: `spring stop` and then retry running your app.